# django.db.utils.OperationalError after makemigrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to `python manage.py makemigrations` for a django app in postgres, but I am getting the follow error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "backend_db" does not exist
```

Before this, I am doing `docker compose` up with the following `docker-compose` and `.env` file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.4
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: backend_db
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ 
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - postgres     

volumes:
  database-data:
    driver: local  

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
```

```
DB_NAME='backend_db'
DB_USER='postgres'
DB_PASSWORD='postgres'
# DB_HOST is localhost or the IP of the machine running postgres
DB_HOST='localhost'  
DB_PORT='5432'
```

The part of the `settings.py` that I define the postgres is the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': get_config(
        'DATABASE_URL',
        'sqlite:///' + BASE_DIR.child('db.sqlite3'),
        cast=db_url
    ),
    'postgres': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_config('DB_NAME', 'backend_db'),
        'USER': get_config('DB_USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': get_config('DB_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
        'HOST': get_config('DB_HOST', 'postgres-service'),
        'PORT': get_config('DB_PORT', '5432')
    }
}
```

Any idea of what causes the error?

Comment: If you go to the db container and execute `\l` do you see your db? IIRC, the default database name is `postgres` so try to change `backend_db` to `postgres`

Comment: @BrianDestura If I go to db container an execute \l, backend_db exists there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use:

```
docker-compose run web python manage.py makemigrations
```

You may need to change `web` to your appropriate service.

Comment: Do you mean the application by service? Because if yes, then I am getting ERROR: No such service: vpp_optimization

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and it turns out that in my case, there was a PostgreSQL server (via Postbird) running on my local machine and the python server was inadvertently connecting to it instead of to the one in the Docker container. Context: I normally run my python app natively (i.e., locally with `python manage.py runserver`) and database services in a Docker container, connected to via port forwarding.

The solution was to kill the local Postgres instance and let the python server connect to the Docker instance